# Library not found after installing Socket.IO-swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using the Socket IO-Swift library in my current project. After installing the Socket.IO-Client-Swift pod file into my project, my FMDB library path is not found, showing this error:

```
library not found for -lAFNetworking
```

I'm using the following pods in my podfile:

```
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 12.1.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'

 pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 3.2.0'

 pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.0.0'

 pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0.0'

 pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.2’

 pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '~> 4.0.9’

 pod 'CrittercismSDK', '~> 5.6.8’

 pod 'SocketIO’, '~> 0.0.1’

 pod 'GPUImage’, '~> 0.1.7’

 pod 'iCarousel’, '~> 1.8.3’

 pod 'TwitterKit'

 pod 'GoogleMaps'

 pod 'GooglePlaces'

 pod 'GooglePlacePicker'

 pod 'Google/SignIn'

 pod 'Firebase/Core’

 pod 'Firebase/Crash'

 pod 'Fabric'

 pod 'Crashlytics'

 pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
 pod 'AWSCognito'
 pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider'
 pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
 pod 'AWSEC2'
 pod 'AWSIoT'
 pod 'AWSKinesis'
 pod 'AWSLambda'
 pod 'AWSLex'
 pod 'AWSMachineLearning'
 pod 'AWSPinpoint'
 pod 'AWSPolly'
 pod 'AWSRekognition'
 pod 'AWSS3'
 pod 'AWSSES'
 pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
 pod 'AWSSNS'
 pod 'AWSSQS'
```

Comment: place your  pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 12.1.0' in use_frameworks!

Comment: already did but not solve my problem

Comment: okay could you tell me the steps which you are following..?

Comment: nothing special dear ... just installing pods and then trying to run/build the project but hitting this error everytime...

Comment: When I receive the error no such module found also a pod error I always check this. Build settings -> search for: framework search paths -> add framework search path : $(SCROOT) and thick reversed.

Comment: not working dude Mar-k

Comment: Maybe try to remove derived data and than clean and build the project. Or try pod deintegrate and than pod install. Otherwise I don't know the solution.

Comment: Are you aware that many of the quote marks in your podfile are actually `&rsquo;` and the like? I don't know if that may cause any issues. I'm not even sure how those could've got in, unless you've been editing your podfile in Word!